# I set INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" but still it looks for websphere

Tags: java, jboss

I am migrating a WebSphere 6 project to JBoss EAP 6.4. And doing so I am changing datasources and connection params.

At one of these I am facing a weird issue. 
Even I set INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY to jboss's

```
   INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
   "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"
```

Still

```
    env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
            "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    initialContext = new InitialContext();
```

this ones initial context is used in an other function (below):

```
    DSReferenceFactory factory = 
            DSReferenceFactory.getInstance();       
    newconn = ((DataSource) 
           factory.initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCENAME)).getConnection();
log.debug("Connection taken");
```

On the line
     factory.initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCENAME)).getConnection();

I throws te below error:

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
   com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
```

I am not using anything with WebSphere in my code. And I am setting jboss one manually as you can see in the code. But still somehow it throws this error which I can not really relate a logic to.

Is there any one who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: what is `DSReferenceFactory`? Share your code for `DSReferenceFactory`.

Comment: Hi, this code Block is the initiation of dsreferencefactory. Then it returns the instance.         
        env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
 "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    initialContext = new InitialContext();

Comment: I think the issue is in this factory initiation. Can you share the whole class of dsreferencefactory?

Comment: Hi, the issue has solved after I removed the initial context factory and re build with maven. And also after I emoved the ws-runtime.jar from the libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has solved after I removed the initial context factory and re build with maven.

And also after I removed the ws-runtime.jar from the libs.

Thanks